# Is there a way to change the color of a specific word/string at run time of a WPF ListBox Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox-control

So all i want is if a specific word will be added in a listbox row/item, at run time, cause i am using a timer to add items at run time from my Database,  i want that specific word/string to have a diferent color.

ie: All new item added that contains the string/word "Aproved", should be colored as green as soon as a new item its added to the WPF ListBox at run time.

```
 private void dispatcherTimerMensagem_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(principalDB.testarConexãoDB()))
        {
            dispatcherTimerVendasFechadas.Stop();
            dispatcherTimerMensagem.Stop();
            LstMensagem.ItemsSource = null;
            LbPbVendasFechadas.ItemsSource = null;
        }
        else
        {
            mensagem = principalDB.selectMessagemUsuario(null);

            if (mensagem != string.Empty)
            {
                this.Activate();
                LstMensagem.Opacity = 1;
                LstMensagem.Items.Add(principalDB.mensagemRemetente + " (" + principalDB.mensagemData + ")" + ": " + mensagem);

                voice.Voice = voice.GetVoices().Item(0);

                myWorkerMensagem.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                myWorkerMensagem.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                myWorkerMensagem.RunWorkerAsync();

                if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(LstMensagem) > 0)
                {
                    Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(LstMensagem, 0);
                    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LstMensagem.Opacity = 0.5;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the LstMensagem will recieve a new item at run time, from the variables declared, in this line of code:

```
 LstMensagem.Items.Add(principalDB.mensagemRemetente + " (" + principalDB.mensagemData + ")" + ": " + mensagem);
```

If a specific word/string comes up, as ie "aproved" i want that string with a different text color,as example, brushed in green.

Comment: You should explain what you have attempted and any relevant code. its hard to give a solution from conjecture.

Comment: I updated my question. Please, see above.

Comment: You could bind the Foreground color of the listbox item Control to the Text. and use a converter to set the color.

Comment: The problem is i don´t want the whole item to be set with a different color, only the specific word/string. If so, can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a TextBlock instead string. For entire item:

```
var text =  principalDB.mensagemRemetente + " (" + principalDB.mensagemData + ")" + ": " + mensagem;

var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = text;

if(text.Contains("aproved"))
    tb.Foreground = Brushes.Green;

LstMensagem.Items.Add(tb);
```

For only part of the item, use the Inlines property to add different formatted texts:

```
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run { Foreground = Brushes.Green, Text = 
principalDB.mensagemRemetente});
tb.Inlines.Add(" (" + principalDB.mensagemData + ")" + ": " + mensagem);

LstMensagem.Items.Add(tb);
```

Comment: ´Sounds great! I´ll give a try tomorrow and let you know asap. Thank you!

Comment: @Iomed, that works perfectly so I voted as the answer.  You gave me an example using code behing and that was what i am looking for. Thank you so much. Btw, is there a way to highlight only that particular word  "aproved" , and not the whole row/item?

Comment: @BerBar, i not see your vote... for highlight only the aproved word, you need extract (by `IndexOf` and `Substring` methods) the text before and after of aproved word, and use the inlines as I showed in the second snippet of code in the example

Comment: @iomed, Certainly cause i don´t have enough SOF reputation. But i voted and still saying it will not be showed public cause of that. Sorry :(.

Comment: @BerBar you need reputation to vte, but you can accept the answer without reputation. for accept the answer click the gray V that appears beside my answer, thanks in advance